# MonoDevelop 2.6 Beta 1 (2.5.90) Targets .NET 1.0 Framework in Csproj files?

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

Can anyone tell me why when I create Monotouch projects in the latest drop of MonoDevelop it is targeting the 1.0 framework instead of 3.5, as my projects in earlier versions do?  This causes it to not be loadable in VS2010, which I tend to use for coding, while building/testing in MonoDevelop.  Here is the version info:

```
Release ID: 20509002
Git revision: 35a0397615c02f7830d46dfcd31a6c0cb86e9f85
Build date: 2011-04-06 03:37:58+0000
```

And here is the difference in the csproj files between versions:

Old:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

New:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v1.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The v3.5 was a bug; MonoTouch projects never targeted the .NET v3.5 framework. They target the MonoTouch framework, which is arbitrarily versioned as v1.0.

Improvements in MD 2.6 have allowed us to deal with custom .NET frameworks in a similar way to  VS 2010. This means that instead of storing the "closest" .NET framework then internally switching it to the correct framework after the project is loaded, we can directly handle particular project types using a particular custom framework.

If you want to load MT project in VS, you already have to make changes to the project - temporarily remove the project flavor GUID (though a trivial VS addin could make that unnecessary). This framework version fix means that you also have to change the target framework to one that VS has. For MonoTouch 4, rather than using .NET 3.5, I would recommend using either Silverlight 4 or .NET 4.

The best solution would be to set VS to actually use the MonoTouch framework, so you'd get accurate code completion and compilation. In VS 2010 that's now possible. Simply set the TargetFrameworkIdentifier of the project to "MonoTouch", then install the custom framework by copying all the MonoTouch framework assemblies to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoTouch\v1.0` and adding a FrameworkList.xml manifest in the RedistList subdirectory.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Stinks, because the "bug" was really useful in that I had a great workflow for coding in VS with Reshaper and ViEmu (MonoDevelop is good, but I just miss the extra help and speed I get from being used to R# and ViEmu).  I also had the trial of Mono Tools for VS installed and that seemed to take care of the different project GUIDs, etc.  I'll have to spend some time trying your suggestions to see if I can get it working again.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I had to make the change as part of the plans to migrate to xbuild/MSBuild build engine - and it should make developing the project in VS better, but you do need to set up the custom framework.

Comment: For now, you could just downgrade to MD 2.4.2.

Comment: Mate, that's all very well, but since many of us actually write cross platform code, throwing it back to v1.0 breaks everything. Could you possibly, please, decide to start Monotouch at 3.5 or 4.0, just for compatability reasons? This is really breaking my stuff.

Comment: You're asking to have two unrelated versions numbers be made similar enough that you can exploit the IDE's ignorance of the different frameworks?

Answer (score 3):

I've created a small open source project that enables you to build MonoTouch projects inside Visual Studio 2010. The readme for the project also explains how to get round the "v1.0" problem for the target framework version.

The project is available at https://github.com/follesoe/VSMonoTouch.

Comment: Awesome, Jonas! I can't wait to try this out.  Thanks for doing this!

Answer (score 0):

Since that's a Monotouch project, nobody expects it to work for Visual Studio or Windows.

Comment: I agree, I think you need to setup MonoDevelop to function as Visual Studio (hotkeys, etc.).  I also use a program called synergy at http://synergy-foss.org/ which helped me use 1 keyboard for both machines and map Ctrl+C appropriately since Command is used on the Mac.

Comment: It worked fine before, but if you see mhutch's post it seems the targetframework was a bug.  You have to include the MT DLLs and do some other tweaking, but I was going along gangbusters coding in VS and building/testing in MonoDevelop until this "bug" was fixed :-/